# How to edit FreeBSD .gz bootfile?

Tags: linux, unix, linux-kernel, embedded-linux, freebsd

I have virtual image of a FreeBSD system and when I mount it I don't see the /etc/ directory and other files, instead is a big loader.gz on the filesystem, that I believe that is extracted during the boot process. I decompressed the loader.gz with gzip and I got it:

```
$ file loader
loader: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (FreeBSD), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), not stripped
```

Using grep I'm able to confirm that the files that I need to edit are inside, however I don't know how to edit it. I tried to mount it without success. How can I modify the contents of loader.gz and use it again?

Can you please give me an example?

I have a Linux system and a Mac to install tools and this FreeBSD image.

Please, help me.

Comment: I'd guess you mounting the wrong partition, but without more detail on this image, how it was created, etc. there's no way to know.

Answer (score 0):

The [loader](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?loader%288%29) program is generally the last stage of the kernel bootstrapping process.

A recent image should have another signature. e.g. for a memory stick image;

```
> file tmp/FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img 
tmp/FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img: Unix Fast File system
[v1] (little-endian), last mounted on , 
last written at Fri Jan 17 00:24:02 2014, 
clean flag 1, number of blocks 681040, number of data blocks 679047, 
number of cylinder groups 13, block size 8192, fragment size 1024,
minimum percentage of free blocks 8, rotational delay 0ms, 
disk rotational speed 60rps, TIME optimization
```

Mounting an image on FreeBSD:

```
# mdconfig -a -t vnode -f tmp/FreeBSD-10.0-RELEASE-amd64-memstick.img -u 1
# mount /dev/md1a /mnt/root/
```

(Linux has the same capability, I just don't remember what its called.)

This image contains `loader` in the `boot/` directory:

```
# ls /mnt/root/
.cshrc        ERRATA.TXT    README.TXT    boot/         lib/          proc/         sys@
.profile      HARDWARE.HTM  RELNOTES.HTM  dev/          libexec/      rescue/       tmp/
COPYRIGHT     HARDWARE.TXT  RELNOTES.TXT  docbook.css   media/        root/         usr/
ERRATA.HTM    README.HTM    bin/          etc/          mnt/          sbin/         var/
# ls /mnt/root/boot/
beastie.4th         check-password.4th  gptzfsboot          menu.4th            support.4th
boot                color.4th           kernel/             menu.rc             userboot.so
boot0               defaults/           loader*             menusets.4th        version.4th
boot0sio            delay.4th           loader.4th          modules/            zfs/
boot1               device.hints        loader.help         pmbr                zfsboot
boot2               firmware/           loader.rc           pxeboot             zfsloader*
brand.4th           frames.4th          mbr                 screen.4th
cdboot              gptboot             menu-commands.4th   shortcuts.4th
```

On my FreeBSD 10 system, loader has another signature;

```
/boot/loader: FreeBSD/i386 demand paged executable
```